# Geolocation | Flutter - Conocer cambio de ubicación

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un error al agregar geolocation: ^0.2.1

Por lo que entiendo es necesario bajar la versión del SDK de Dart, pero esto me afectaria otras libreria. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Mi proposito en este punto es que el telefono me indique cuando exista un cambio en su ubicación.

Existe alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al agregar Geolocator me indica este error, y no le eh encontrado solución, no se en donde ubicar androidx.core:core

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que error te aparece, sería bueno que agregues a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: Disculpa, ya coloque la imagen. @diegoveloper

Comment: Saludos te envie una imagen en la siguiente respuesta.

Comment: Elimina esa respuesta, edita tu pregunta y agrega la imagen ahí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como puedes ver en en pub.dartlang, el plugin `geolocation` no es compatible con Dart 2.0 , te recomiendo que uses el plugin `geolocator`.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator

También tiene todo lo que necesitas para capturar la ubicación de los dispositivos.

**Actualización**

Agrega estos valores en el archivo gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```